# How can I transfer a call to different queue / flow after loop prompts timeout in AWS Connect?

Tags: amazon-connect

When customers are in my default customer queue, I would like to give them the ability to leave a voicemail if nobody is answering their call.

What I currently have:

- As part of the inbound flow, the customer eventually has the customer queue flow set to "Default customer queue" and queue set to "BasicQueue".
- The "Default customer queue" flow looks like this:

  - Loop prompts, timeout after 30s.
  - Get customer input (apologise that nobody has answered, press 1 to leave a voicemail, otherwise continue to hold).
  - If the customer presses "1", set the customer queue flow to "Voicemail Queue Flow" and transfer to the "VoicemailQueue".
  - If the customer does anything else, the flow ends and loops back to the beginning.

The problem I'm having is that even when the customer presses "1", the customer still loops back round to the beginning of the default customer queue. I'm more confused because I have another flow elsewhere that does almost the exact same thing and works just fine!

Is anyone able to give me any pointers? Is it possible to somehow break out of the "Loop prompts" behaviour?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Without visually seeing for sure - once the customer presses 1, you should have a Set Working Queue Box to change the Q before or after you set the customer queue then a Transfer to Queue Box.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).